# How to access a SOLR-synonym dictionary from a SOLR client?

Tags: solr, spell-checking, synonym

Imagine a search engine that doesn't have the word 'Iran' in the index. If a user searches for 'Iran' we have no results. We could use SOLR's spelling correction and suggest 'iron' instead. Alternatively, we could use a synonym dictionary and replace 'Iran' by 'Persia' (assuming 'Persia' is in the index). However, we don't know what the user wants to search for. So I would like to present both words, 'Persia' and 'iron', as suggestions.

Thus my question: can I access the synonym dictionary from the SOLR-client?

I am not sure, whether this should be solved by SOLR at all. It would of course be easy to store the synonym list e.g. in a SQL-Database and get suggestions from there. On the other hand it might be good to keep the number of systems and dependencies as small as possible.

Comment: Interestingly, the spelling component gives spelling suggestions even for terms that were introduced by query expansion. So the user can get suggestions to correct words that he never typed in.

Maybe, I could do query expansion (wit a synonym dictionary) on an empty field and pick the expanded terms from the spelling suggestions. Sounds simple though probably not the most eegant way.

Answer (score 0):

You can access synonyms file using simple GET method and then you can do the mapping.

> localhost:8983/solr/#/coreName/files?file=synonyms.txt

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that. But in that case I also could copy that file once by hand to the server where the client is running.